# How to return to app after clicking on a Notification?

Tags: delphi, android-intent, android-pendingintent, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using this code to keep an ongoing notification for the user, but how should I proceed to correctly return to the app after clicking it?

Ps.: the actual code contains `ntfManager.cancelAll;` on `OnFormClose` and `OnFormDestroy` to prevent from app being killed and the icon remains.

```
procedure TForm1.FormSaveState(Sender: TObject);
var
  ntfManager: JNotificationManager;
  ntfBuilder: JNotificationCompat_Builder;
  Ntf: JNotification;
  contentIntent: JPendingIntent;
  Intent: JIntent;
  const
  r_drawable_ic_btn_speak_now = 17301668;
begin
  Form1.Tag := 1;
  ntfBuilder:= TJNotificationCompat_Builder.JavaClass.init(TAndroidHelper.Context);
  //ntfBuilder.setSmallIcon(TAndroidHelper.Context.getResources.getIdentifier(StringToJString('ic_test'), StringToJString('drawable'), TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName));
  ntfBuilder.setSmallIcon(r_drawable_ic_btn_speak_now);
  ntfBuilder.setContentTitle(StrToJCharSequence('Content Title'));
  ntfBuilder.setContentText(StrToJCharSequence('Content Test'));
  ntfBuilder.setAutoCancel(True);
  ntfBuilder.setOngoing(True);

  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  // What should I do with this intent for returning to the app?

  contentIntent := TJPendingIntent.Create;
  // How I add the Intent on this PendingIntent?
  // Where I should add the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag?

  ntfBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

  Ntf:= ntfBuilder.build;

  ntfManager:= TJNotificationManager.Wrap((TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
  ntfManager.notify(1, Ntf);
end;
```

Comment: [Try this](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=847227).

Comment: This is perfect

Comment: @Victoria if you post the relevant part of the solution, you might get an accepted answer, plus the answer will still be found here even in case the forum article disappears

Comment: @mjn, good point, but I still have no environment to test. I'm answering mostly FireDAC questions, because I can read the source, and to be honest, I'm not a score hunter here. I appreciate any feedback that something I answered works :) Feel free to add answer by yourself ;) –

Answer (score -1):

```
AIntent :=TJIntent.Create;
AIntent.setClass(SharedActivityContext, SharedActivityContext.getClass);
PendingIntentClick := TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getActivity(TAndroidHelper.Context,0,
       AIntent,
       TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be helpful if you edited your answer to add an explanation of how your code works.